# How to use RETURNING for query.update() with sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to specify the return values for a specific update in sqlalchemy.

The documentation of the underlying [update statement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update) (sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update) says it accepts a "returning" argument and the docs for the [query object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) state that query.update() accepts a dictionary "update_args" which will be passed as the arguments to the query statement.

Therefore my code looks like this:

```
session.query(
  ItemClass
).update(
  {ItemClass.value: value_a},
  synchronize_session='fetch',
  update_args={
    'returning': (ItemClass.id,)
  }
)
```

However, this does not seem to work. It just returns the regular integer.

My question is now: Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not possible with a query object and I need to manually construct statements or write raw sql?

Comment: It's not possible. [`Query.update`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) is clearly documented to return "the count of rows matched as returned by the database’s “row count” feature", not the result of the update query.

Answer (score 8):

The full solution that worked for me was to use the SQLAlchemy table object directly.

You can get that table object and the columns from your model easily by doing

```
table = Model.__table__
columns = table.columns
```

Then with this table object, I can replicate what you did in the question:

```
from your_settings import db

update_statement = table.update().returning(table.id)\
    .where(columns.column_name=value_one)\
    .values(column_name='New column name')
result = db.session.execute(update_statement)

tuple_of_results = result.fetchall()

db.session.commit()
```

The tuple_of_results variable would contain a tuple of the results.
Note that you would have to run `db.session.commit()` in order to persist the changes to the database as you it is currently running within a transaction.

You could perform an update based on the current value of a column by doing something like:

```
update_statement = table.update().returning(table.id)\
    .where(columns.column_name=value_one)\
    .values(like_count=table_columns.like_count+1)
```

This would increment our numeric `like_count` column by one.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi! I'd like to ensure that other threads can't go between the update and the commit. Does this solution accomplish that?

Comment: You would have to make the transaction(or db session) SERIALIZABLE. See this l[ink](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-isolation-for-individual-transactions) for more details

Comment: You can get more information about DB isolation levels from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gxyut1VLcs&ab_channel=Techtud)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a snippet from the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-update-returning):

```
# UPDATE..RETURNING
result = table.update().returning(table.c.col1, table.c.col2).\
    where(table.c.name=='foo').values(name='bar')
print result.fetchall()
```

Comment: Don't believe that works for the way they're using `query.update()` ...

Comment: what does `table` mean here? what is `table.c`?

Comment: @mymedia `table` is the sqlalchemy Table object. `table.c` is the collection of columns in that table. Check out https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html

Comment: @courtsimas the APIs are a bit different if you work with `selectables` or with `session` and `query` objects, but all support `returning` if the backend supports returning I think.